# Customizing Index view in Contacts view

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview, xcode4.6.3

I am creating a contacts view using customized table view cell. Is there a way i can leave some space between the view and the cell on the right side so that i can place the alphabetical index on that space. Also can i customize the index view to modify the height and color of the alphabets in the index view.